# How to put Vertically swiped ViewPager in a Horizontally swiped ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

I'm customizing my Android app to swipe in the four directions, I'm using `ViewPager` to swipe **Horizontally** and [VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager) to swipe vertically *(this is like a modification of [DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/) as the original one is deprecated)* . the problem is When containing the `ViewPager` in the `VerticalViewPager`, the **Vertical** swiping works only and when containing `VerticalViewPager` in the `ViewPager` the **Horizontal** swipe works only, this is my code for the first state:

```
VerticalViewPager verticalViewPager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vertical_pager);
        verticalViewPager.setAdapter(new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        verticalViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
                int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
                int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

                if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                    view.setAlpha(0);

                } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                    // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
                    float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
                    float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
                    float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
                    if (position < 0) {
                        view.setTranslationY(vertMargin - horzMargin / 2);
                    } else {
                        view.setTranslationY(-vertMargin + horzMargin / 2);
                    }

                    // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
                    view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
                    view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

                    // Fade the page relative to its size.
                    view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +
                            (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                                    (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

                } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                    // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                    view.setAlpha(0);
                }
            }
        });

        verticalViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager Tab = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
        Tab.setCurrentItem(1);
```

The **TabPagerAdapter** class:

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            //Fragment for Left side
            return new AC_Left();
        case 1:
           //Fragment for Center side
            return new AC_Center();
        case 2:
            //Fragment for Right side
            return new AC_Right();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

**AC_Left**, **AC_Right**, and **AC_Center** are similar `fragments` except of the `layout` returned:

```
public class AC_Center extends Fragment {
  @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View ac_center_frag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_center_fragment, container, false);
          return ac_center_frag;

  }
}
```

And the **XML** file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

  <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonBar"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

  <com.example.myapp.VerticalViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vertical_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </com.example.myapp.VerticalViewPager>

 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm working on this myself.  How far back do you have to support?

Comment: @btate what do you mean by how far back do i have to support

Comment: What minimum os version do you have to support.

Comment: @btate it must be 4.0 at least

Comment: I have the same requirements.  I'm getting pretty close to a functional demo.  I can send it to you when I'm there.

Comment: @btate well, thanks a lot, i'll wait.

Comment: What are your requirements for wrapping?  I have a working grid that wraps around to the beginning/end in all directions so far.  I'm still working on stopping the paging when it hits the end of any direction.

Comment: @btate well, I don't want it to wrap, I want it to hit the end also

Comment: By the way you can use RecyclerView with LinearSnapHelper and ViewPager inside each item.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134094/recyclerview-horizontal-scroll-snap-in-center

Comment: @Qamar Thank you I will check that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a library for this with a sample application and put it on github.  Basically it maintains a view port and updates the view pager on each page change.  There's an adapter you have to implement to give it fragments for each row, column index.  It's admittedly a little hacked together, but should work in the mean time.  There's a bit mask you can set to have it wrap in whatever directions you need.  Set it to GRID_WRAP_NONE to have it not wrap at all.

https://github.com/btate/BTGridPager-Android

This might not be exactly what you need but it should get you started.