# Android ViewPager Detect Vertical Swipe

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I would like to allow the ViewPager to swipe normally to the right/left as it is and detect Vertical Flings. I tried to assign a `GestureDetector` but the problem is that returning `true` from the method `public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)` disables the normal horizontal swiping of the ViewPager. Any ideas how to allow both?

Answer (score 0):

There are already some custom controls for this. Try looking into these threads of how to implement a Vertical ViewPager.

1. http://vision-apps.blogspot.ro/2013/05/4-directions-swipe-navigation.html
2. [How to put Vertically swiped ViewPager in a Horizontally swiped ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130418/how-to-put-vertically-swiped-viewpager-in-a-horizontally-swiped-viewpager)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889530/vertical-viewpager-implementation

Hope this helps.:)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I checked some of them before but I don't need it to swipe, I just need to detect the vertical fling. totally failed to customize it.

Comment: So what you want is to have like a vertical scrollview inside your viewpager? I mean what is the purpose of the vertical fling?

Comment: I want to detect the vertical fling to change the Fragment list of the adapter for the viewpager.

Comment: Hey @AhmedEmad  ,Did you find any work around ..Actually I'm also stucked on this