# RecyclerView horizontal scroll snap in center

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a carousel-like view here using RecyclerView, I want the item to snap in the middle of the screen when scrolling, one item at a time. I've tried using `recyclerView.setScrollingTouchSlop(RecyclerView.TOUCH_SLOP_PAGING);`

but the view is still scrolling smoothly, I've also tried to implement my own logic using scroll listener like so:

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    Log.v("Offset ", recyclerView.getWidth() + "");
                    if (newState == 0) {
                        try {
                               recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition());
                                recyclerView.scrollBy(20,0);
                            if (layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() >= recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
                                Beam refresh = new Beam();
                                refresh.execute(createUrl());
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

The swipe from right to left is working fine now, but not the other way around, what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 192):

With [`LinearSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html), this is now very easy.

All you need to do is this:

```
SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

**Update**

Available since 25.1.0, [`PagerSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper.html) can help achieve `ViewPager` like effect. Use it as you would use the `LinearSnapHelper`.

Old workaround:

If you wish for it to behave akin to the `ViewPager`, try this instead:

```
LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper() {
    @Override
    public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        View centerView = findSnapView(layoutManager);
        if (centerView == null) 
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

        int position = layoutManager.getPosition(centerView);
        int targetPosition = -1;
        if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
            if (velocityX < 0) {
                targetPosition = position - 1;
            } else {
                targetPosition = position + 1;
            }
        }

        if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
            if (velocityY < 0) {
                targetPosition = position - 1;
            } else {
                targetPosition = position + 1;
            }
        }

        final int firstItem = 0;
        final int lastItem = layoutManager.getItemCount() - 1;
        targetPosition = Math.min(lastItem, Math.max(targetPosition, firstItem));
        return targetPosition;
    }
};
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

The implementation above just returns the position next to the current item (centered) based on the direction of the velocity, regardless of the magnitude.

The former one is a first party solution included in the Support Library version 24.2.0.
Meaning you have to add this to your app module's `build.gradle` or update it.

```
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0"
```

Comment: This did not work for me (but the solution by @Albert Vila Calvo did). Have you implemented it? Are we supposed to override methods from it? I would think that the class should do all of the work out of the box

Comment: Yes, hence the answer. I have not tested thoroughly however. To be clear, I did this with a horizontal `LinearLayoutManager` where the views all were regular in size. Nothing else but the snippet above is needed.

Comment: @galaxigirl apologies, I have understood what you meant and have made some edit acknowledging that, please do comment. This is an alternate solution with the `LinearSnapHelper`.

Comment: This worked just right for me. @galaxigirl overriding this method helps in that the linear snap helper will otherwise snap to the nearest item when scroll is settling, not exactly just the next/previous item. Thanks a lot for this, razzledazzle

Comment: LinearSnapHelper was the initial solution that worked for me, but it seems that PagerSnapHelper gave the swiping a better animation.

Answer (score 107):

## Google I/O 2019 Update

*[ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2) is here!*

Google [just announced](https://youtu.be/td3Kd7fOROw?t=1702) at the talk 'What's New in Android' (aka 'The Android keynote') that they are working on a new ViewPager based on RecyclerView!

From the slides:

> Like ViewPager, but better
>
> - Easy migration from ViewPager
> - Based on RecyclerView
> - Right-to-Left mode support
> - Allows vertical paging
> - Improved dataset change notifications

You can check the latest version [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) and the release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2). There is also an [official sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-viewpager2). *Update Dec. 2021: sample has moved to [this other repo](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/ViewPager2).*

*Personal opinion:* I think this is a really needed addition. I've recently had a lot of trouble with the `PagerSnapHelper` [oscillating left right indefinitely](https://doc-3nhg-3p7g-issuetracker.googleusercontent.com/attachments/8jko11atetdmk9j61dmqmjc307np3pl3/pl6tit1fvhpqbqkar6clqciqdq6qsfag/1560002400000/192731/106934035569275288751/130570590::25822537::192731?dat=AFNnbnnUeLmd2rSpMY6a-8ewGEo61DvJJ-8GmOgdm5YHUZ2JViOsiaJMZmaZDwMYo0xIh6b5tMq8shy1OctWy42_6WaiYk2tyH6zqNez3-AALjInp_NkmQLvC36n50EHbr59txDEvgGUDsU8IemYTmwA5ZQYeZlzpLARgKMeKQxNR6pcn2sTLU8fsmkmd3O1yXpEUWT_VFIhiVTIT6cmxBmX0QUVnUQaTvjFC8PeuLwIt5lOXeremzPgpzF1nXEBWHs0YPp7sFYFMc2aBK92Tf4xojhhld-LftbHN92bUettPrbRpxTBwAGggmpig2JipCMbI431t6bbFbwjiU_rQKFjKrBf1hHpYbYW-iaB_UuNwucWcCAAleGAcxiO6QLJnegcGipC21dPoOAGLzGJd4lYkG2408XDY-rafliIg1K3ntDa-_CzznhLqIhsFKJDfOW-TxOGZ9T0IPOcNrRzk09vIvKWxoqaC-wM7FhzVT6XG6Gt9yM8CLorxQdbO1KJ7XQNBFS7FGP8rDz2ejZC4xGsW8NQSdpSMg39cBMYIMvixMtkO-sz0G2kNHjnDSEVD4jc7i_h6Zux-5y7-ovj2Lc1kkRhZIoGFFqz5GlIIkW88gOHH7nzcw91zRSj997FCOCneBFkjwnE73zxCajEYHFBkE5ShFfoxkUeteQ2gFaYTeLRtGRwgTs&u=0&download=false&nonce=r3vu32ul7mnaa&user=106934035569275288751&hash=0fha8o7bbmq6qotbj72g59htrq1uk6nf) - see [the ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130570590) I've opened.

---

## New answer (2016)

You can now just use a [SnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SnapHelper).

If you want a center-aligned snapping behavior similar to [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager) then use [PagerSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/PagerSnapHelper):

```
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

There is also a [LinearSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearSnapHelper). I've tried it and if you fling with energy then it scrolls 2 items with 1 fling. Personally I didn't like it, but just decide by yourself - trying it only takes seconds.

---

## Original answer (2016)

After *many* hours of trying 3 different solutions found here in SO I've finally built a solution that mimics very closely the behavior found in a `ViewPager`.

The solution is based on the @eDizzle [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29171652/4034572), which I believe I've improved enough to say that it works almost like a `ViewPager`.

**Important: my `RecyclerView` items width is exactly the same as the screen. I haven't tried with other sizes. Also I use it with an horizontal `LinearLayoutManager`. I think that you will need to adapt the code if you want vertical scroll.**

Here you have the code:

```
public class SnappyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    // Use it with a horizontal LinearLayoutManager
    // Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29171652/4034572

    public SnappyRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SnappyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SnappyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();

        int screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

        // views on the screen
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        View lastView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleItemPosition);
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        View firstView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisibleItemPosition);

        // distance we need to scroll
        int leftMargin = (screenWidth - lastView.getWidth()) / 2;
        int rightMargin = (screenWidth - firstView.getWidth()) / 2 + firstView.getWidth();
        int leftEdge = lastView.getLeft();
        int rightEdge = firstView.getRight();
        int scrollDistanceLeft = leftEdge - leftMargin;
        int scrollDistanceRight = rightMargin - rightEdge;

        if (Math.abs(velocityX) < 1000) {
            // The fling is slow -> stay at the current page if we are less than half through,
            // or go to the next page if more than half through

            if (leftEdge > screenWidth / 2) {
                // go to next page
                smoothScrollBy(-scrollDistanceRight, 0);
            } else if (rightEdge < screenWidth / 2) {
                // go to next page
                smoothScrollBy(scrollDistanceLeft, 0);
            } else {
                // stay at current page
                if (velocityX > 0) {
                    smoothScrollBy(-scrollDistanceRight, 0);
                } else {
                    smoothScrollBy(scrollDistanceLeft, 0);
                }
            }
            return true;

        } else {
            // The fling is fast -> go to next page

            if (velocityX > 0) {
                smoothScrollBy(scrollDistanceLeft, 0);
            } else {
                smoothScrollBy(-scrollDistanceRight, 0);
            }
            return true;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(state);

        // If you tap on the phone while the RecyclerView is scrolling it will stop in the middle.
        // This code fixes this. This code is not strictly necessary but it improves the behaviour.

        if (state == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();

            int screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

            // views on the screen
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            View lastView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleItemPosition);
            int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            View firstView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisibleItemPosition);

            // distance we need to scroll
            int leftMargin = (screenWidth - lastView.getWidth()) / 2;
            int rightMargin = (screenWidth - firstView.getWidth()) / 2 + firstView.getWidth();
            int leftEdge = lastView.getLeft();
            int rightEdge = firstView.getRight();
            int scrollDistanceLeft = leftEdge - leftMargin;
            int scrollDistanceRight = rightMargin - rightEdge;

            if (leftEdge > screenWidth / 2) {
                smoothScrollBy(-scrollDistanceRight, 0);
            } else if (rightEdge < screenWidth / 2) {
                smoothScrollBy(scrollDistanceLeft, 0);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice catch the on onScrollStateChanged(); otherwise, a small bug is present if we swipe slowly the RecyclerView.
Thanks!

Comment: To support margins (android:layout_marginStart="16dp") I tried with int screenwidth = getWidth(); and it seems to work.

Comment: AWESOOOMMEEEEEEEEE

Comment: How does this work with lower API's? Since `RecyclerView` needs to be used with `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` to be adaptable for lower API's and this method requires you to use your own xml tag.

Comment: @Albert your solution is great - I was unsuccessful using the new LinearSnapHelper class. Have you implemented it?

Comment: @galaxigirl no, I haven't tryied LinearSnapHelper yet. I just updated the answer so that people knows about the official solution. My solution works without any issue on my app.

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo I tried LinearSnapHelper. LinearSnapHelper works with a Scroller. It scrolls and snaps based on the gravity and the fling velocity. Higher the speed more pages are scrolled. I wouldn't recommend it for a ViewPager like behaviour.

Comment: @mipreamble made some modification for that behavior, please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39036351/4803633 and provide feedback.

Comment: @razzledazzle I like the solution. But, the target position of the item is based on how long the drag is. If the drag is longer then targetPosition is position +/- 2.

Comment: to support a reversed layout order
`int lastVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.getReverseLayout() ? linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() : linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
  View lastView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleItemPosition);
  int firstVisibleItemPosition = linearLayoutManager.getReverseLayout() ? linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() : linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
  View firstView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisibleItemPosition);`

Comment: I tested the SnapHelper and worked as a ViewPager (exactly what I wanted) with only 2 lines of code !!!
        `SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);`

Comment: Worked like a charm.Thanks

Comment: UI misaligned upon rotation of the phone.

Comment: How can i achieve same for vertical scrolling recycler view ?

Comment: @AlbertVilaCalvo so how can I get the current item for that?

Comment: It's 2021 - is ViewPager2 still the way? I'm about to give it a go with this sample from Android https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/ViewPager2

Answer (score 52):

If the goal is to make the `RecyclerView` mimic the behavior of `ViewPager` there is quite easy approach

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

By using `PagerSnapHelper` you can get the behavior like `ViewPager`

Comment: I am using `LinearSnapHelper` instead of `PagerSnapHelper ` and it works for me

Comment: Yes, there is no snap effect in `LinearSnapHelper`

Comment: this sticks the item on the view enables scrolable

Comment: @BoonyaKitpitak, I tried `LinearSnapHelper`, and it snaps to a middle item. `PagerSnapHelper` hinders to easily scroll (at least, a list of images).

Comment: @BoonyaKitpitak can you tell me how to do this, one item in cente fully visible and side items are half visible?

Answer (score 31):

You need to use findFirstVisibleItemPosition for going in the opposite direction. And for detecting which direction the swipe was in, youll need to get either the fling velocity or the change in x. I approached this problem from a slightly different angle than you have.

Create a new class that extends the RecyclerView class and then override RecyclerView's fling method like so:

```
@Override
public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();

//these four variables identify the views you see on screen.
    int lastVisibleView = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    int firstVisibleView = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    View firstView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisibleView);
    View lastView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleView);

//these variables get the distance you need to scroll in order to center your views.
//my views have variable sizes, so I need to calculate side margins separately.     
//note the subtle difference in how right and left margins are calculated, as well as
//the resulting scroll distances.
    int leftMargin = (screenWidth - lastView.getWidth()) / 2;
    int rightMargin = (screenWidth - firstView.getWidth()) / 2 + firstView.getWidth();
    int leftEdge = lastView.getLeft();
    int rightEdge = firstView.getRight();
    int scrollDistanceLeft = leftEdge - leftMargin;
    int scrollDistanceRight = rightMargin - rightEdge;

//if(user swipes to the left) 
    if(velocityX > 0) smoothScrollBy(scrollDistanceLeft, 0);
    else smoothScrollBy(-scrollDistanceRight, 0);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where is screenWidth defined?

Comment: @Itsai : Oops! Good question. It's a variable I set elsewhere in the class. It's the screen width of the device in pixels, not density pixels, since the smoothScrollBy method requires the number of pixels you want it to scroll by.

Comment: @ltsai You can change to getWidth() (recyclerview.getWidth()) instead of screenWidth. screenWidth doesn't work correctly when RecyclerView's smaller than screen' width.

Comment: I tried to extend RecyclerView but I'm getting "Error inflating class custom RecyclerView". Can you help? Thanks

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes : You might want to search for that in another question feed. It's pretty out of scope with the initial question here.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes : you have to create all three constructors matching super class.

Answer (score 8):

Just add `padding` and `margin` to `recyclerView` and `recyclerView item`:

**recyclerView item:**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" <!-- here -->
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" <!-- here  -->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

   <!-- child views -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

**recyclerView:**

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp" <!-- here -->
    android:paddingRight="8dp" <!-- here -->
    android:clipToPadding="false" <!-- important!-->
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

and set `PagerSnapHelper` :

```
int displayWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
parentLayout.getLayoutParams().width = displayWidth - Utils.dpToPx(16) * 4;
SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

dp to px:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to achieve variable padding between items? like if the first and last card dont need to be centered to show more of the next/prev cards vs the intermediate cards being centered?

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
/**
 * Horizontal linear layout manager whose smoothScrollToPosition() centers
 * on the target item
 */
class ItemLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private int centeredItemOffset;

    public ItemLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller = new Scroller(recyclerView.getContext());
        linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
    }

    public void setCenteredItemOffset(int centeredItemOffset) {
        this.centeredItemOffset = centeredItemOffset;
    }

    /**
     * ********** Inner Classes **********
     */

    private class Scroller extends LinearSmoothScroller {

        public Scroller(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            return ItemLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int calculateDxToMakeVisible(View view, int snapPreference) {
            return super.calculateDxToMakeVisible(view, SNAP_TO_START) + centeredItemOffset;
        }
    }
}
```

I pass this layout manager to the RecycledView and set the offset required to center items. All my items have the same width so constant offset is ok

Answer (score 0):

`PagerSnapHelper` doesn't work with `GridLayoutManager` with spanCount > 1, so my solution under this circumstance is:

```java
class GridPagerSnapHelper : PagerSnapHelper() {
    override fun findTargetSnapPosition(layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager?, velocityX: Int, velocityY: Int): Int {
        val forwardDirection = if (layoutManager?.canScrollHorizontally() == true) {
            velocityX > 0
        } else {
            velocityY > 0
        }
        val centerPosition = super.findTargetSnapPosition(layoutManager, velocityX, velocityY)
        return centerPosition +
            if (forwardDirection) (layoutManager as GridLayoutManager).spanCount - 1 else 0
    }
}
```