# Android RecyclerView Snapping Effect Overriding fling method

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement this override method [RecyclerView horizontal scroll snap in center.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134094/recyclerview-horizontal-scroll-snap-in-center)

But I keep getting a run time error. Here is my code:

```
    public class custom_fling extends RecyclerView{
    private Point size = new Point();
    public custom_fling(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();

//these four variables identify the views you see on screen.
        int lastVisibleView = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        int firstVisibleView = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        View firstView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisibleView);
        View lastView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleView);

//these variables get the distance you need to scroll in order to center your views.
//my views have variable sizes, so I need to calculate side margins separately.
//note the subtle difference in how right and left margins are calculated, as well as
//the resulting scroll distances.
        int leftMargin = (size.x - lastView.getWidth()) / 2;
        int rightMargin = (size.x - firstView.getWidth()) / 2 + firstView.getWidth();
        int leftEdge = lastView.getLeft();
        int rightEdge = firstView.getRight();
        int scrollDistanceLeft = leftEdge - leftMargin;
        int scrollDistanceRight = rightMargin - rightEdge;

//if(user swipes to the left)
        if(velocityX > 0) smoothScrollBy(scrollDistanceLeft, 0);
        else smoothScrollBy(-scrollDistanceRight, 0);

        return true;
    }
}
```

I believe my issue is to do with the casting of my RecyclerView. I am trying to cast it to custom_fling. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: what's the runtime error?