# ViewPager (with multiple items) - How to always centre the items excepts the first and last?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to develop a component similar to iOS Facebook app event component.
It should be a ViewPager that also reveals the next and previous (if position > 0) items.

The actual items should always be in the centre **except** the first item that should stick to the left and the last item that should stick to the right.

When overriding `getPageWidth` - it indeed also shows the next and previous, but all the actual items stick to the left.

```
   @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
       return (float) (0.7);
    }
```

[This library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1489) for example, centres all items **including** the first, which is not what I want

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up using RecyclerView (yes... RecyclerView) with overriding "onFling" method, as can bee seen in this post:
[RecyclerView horizontal scroll snap in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134094/recyclerview-horizontal-scroll-snap-in-center)

Comment: Do you have sample snippet? Care to share? Thanks!

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes look at the link I posted, the code is there