# Horizontal RecyclerView vs ViewPager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I need to show a fixed-length list of items like below:
[image]

Which approach should I use? ViewPager or Horizontal RecyclerView.
And what is the advantages (performance, ...) of ViewPager/Horizontal RecyclerView over the other in this case?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView vs ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167839/recyclerview-vs-viewpager)

Comment: Hi, I see some projects using ViewPager to do this task. I want to know what is the best approach? And why? Thanks!

Comment: Update you question and tags with what languages you are using please? Java, Kotlin, xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Performance**

So in terms of performance, I would most likely always go with [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) as it recycles items when they are off screen, were as the [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) doesn't.

**How to**

So todo this, you need to set the orientation of your `RecyclerView` to horizontal.

xml:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

or Java (runtime):

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Then to get the `RecyclerView` to act like a `ViewPager` and snap to items, you can use a [LinearSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper).

Everything you are looking for is actually explained in a nice tutorial [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8). Or if you want to dive in and just look and learn for yourself, here is the [GitHub link](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/SnapHelperExample) of the tutorials sample project.

Comment: PagerAdapter docs say: *"PagerAdapter is more general than the adapters used for AdapterViews. Instead of providing a View recycling mechanism directly ViewPager uses callbacks to indicate the steps taken during an update. A PagerAdapter may implement a form of View recycling if desired or use a more sophisticated method of managing page Views such as Fragment transactions where each page is represented by its own Fragment."* - so its up to you how you do that

Comment: ViewPager does recycle items when they are off screen. you can control this behavior using `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit`

Answer (score 0):

Both pskink and Anthony Cannon answers are great.
We can implement recycling mechanism PagerAdapter like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19020687/5154523